# Adding elements of a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

so I'm quite new to prolog and I have to add up all the elements of a list.

```
listSum([],0).
listSum([Head|Tail], Sum) :- listSum(Tail,TailSum), Sum is Head + TailSum.
```

The goal is to make this tail-recursive and I was wondering if that was a better way to do it than this

```
listSum([],0).
listSum(List, Sum) :- listSum(List,Sum,0).
listSum([H|T], Sum, S) :- S1 is S+H, listSum(T, Sum, S1).
listSum([], Sum, S) :- Sum is S.
```

Or is that perfectly fine to do? Just looking to see if there's any obvious way to improve the above code that I'm missing out on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks perfectly fine to me. You can save yourself some writing by not doing the unnecessary stuff. First, you get 0 from two separate places; it would be enough to get it from one. Also, "output" arguments are supposed to come after all other arguments.

```
list_sum(L, S) :-
    list_sum(L, 0, S).
```

Then, you don't need the `is/2` in the base case:

```
list_sum([], S, S).
list_sum([X|Xs], S0, S) :-
    S1 is S0 + X,
    list_sum(Xs, S1, S).
```

Of course, you could decide to actually save one step in the tail-recursive definition:

```
list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([X|Xs], S) :-
    list_sum(Xs, X, S).

list_sum([], S0, S) :- S is S0.
list_sum([X|Xs], S0, S) :-
    S1 is S0 + X,
    list_sum(Xs, S1, S).
```

You should recognize that the second version is a fold:

```
list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([X|Xs], S) :-
    foldl(add, Xs, X, S).

add(X, Y, S) :- S is X+Y.
```

Or, even directly:

```
list_sum(List, Sum) :- foldl(add, List, 0, Sum).
```